# left outer join from different database

Tags: c#, linq, left-join, outer-join

i'm having trouble with left outer join

i only want the cj_id(table1 in bd1) where c.ref(table1 in bd1) is not found in ref(table2 in bd2)

so i can remove some registries from db1 that have cj_id instead of ref

for this i'm using this code:

```
var query1 = from a in dbPT.table2
                        join b in dataB.table1
                        on a.Ref equals b.ref into c
                        from x in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select x.CJ_ID;
```

i can't get it to return a string with a cj_id

Comment: What kind of database is this ? SQLServer, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, other...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has you can see in here [Joining Two Entity Sets from Different Contexts](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a6093d7-c7ea-43ce-bd01-19c4b1fba724/joining-two-entity-sets-from-different-contexts?forum=adodotnetentityframework) 
the join is done in the server side, and if you use diferent server there is no way you can do this